# sort and number within levels of a factor in r

Tags: r

if i have the following data frame G:

```
z    type   x   
1     a     4
2     a     5 
3     a     6
4     b     1
5     b     0.9
6     c     4
```

I am trying to get:

```
z    type   x   y
3     a     6   3
2     a     5   2
1     a     4   1
4     b     1   2
5     b     0.9 1
6     c     4   1
```

I.e. i want to sort the whole data frame within the levels of factor `type` based on vector `x`. Get the length of of each level `a = 3   b=2  c=1` and then number in a decreasing fashion in a new vector `y`.

My starting place is currently with `sort()`

```
tapply(y, x, sort)
```

Would it be best to first try and use sapply to split everything first?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many ways to skin this cat.  Here is one solution using base R and vectorized code in two steps (without any `apply`):

1. Sort the data using `order` and `xtfrm`
2. Use `rle` and `sequence` to genereate the sequence.

Replicate your data:

```
dat <- read.table(text="
z    type   x   
1     a     4
2     a     5 
3     a     6
4     b     1
5     b     0.9
6     c     4
", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Two lines of code:

```
r <- dat[order(dat$type, -xtfrm(dat$x)), ]
r$y <- sequence(rle(r$type)$lengths)
```

Results in:

```
r
  z type   x y
3 3    a 6.0 1
2 2    a 5.0 2
1 1    a 4.0 3
4 4    b 1.0 1
5 5    b 0.9 2
6 6    c 4.0 1
```

---

The call to `order` is slightly complicated. Since you are sorting one column in ascending order and a second in descending order, use the helper function `xtfrm`. See `?xtfrm` for details, but it is also described in `?order`.

Comment: hey both great solutions.  I had not seen xtfrm before.  very useful.  i wanted the highest number in `x` to have they highest `y` so deleted the `-` from `xtfrm` and its a perfect result thank you

Comment: @Andrie I hadn't seen `xtfrm` either but don't really get what it does.What is it doing here that the negative won't do? [the help file isn't that terrific on this function]

Comment: @user1322296 OK, in that case you don't need the `xtfrm` at all - it will just slow things down.

Comment: @TylerRinker The `xtfrm` idiom will also work for strings, but in this case you are correct, one doesn't need it.

Answer (score 4):

I like Andrie's better:

```
dat <- read.table(text="z    type   x   
1     a     4
2     a     5 
3     a     6
4     b     1
5     b     0.9
6     c     4", header=T)
```

Three lines of code:

```
dat <- dat[order(dat$type), ]
x <- by(dat, dat$type, nrow)
dat$y <- unlist(sapply(x, function(z) z:1))
```

I Edited my response to adapt for the comments Andrie mentioned.  This works but if you went this route instead of Andrie's you're crazy.

Comment: You need to replace that last `rep(x,x)` with `seq_len(x)` and then it should work. Nice solution.

Comment: @Andrie, I think it works as it is.  The 2nd line gives me the lengths of each factor (what your use of `rle` does) which is `c(3, 2, 1)`.  Then I use `rep` to repeat each one of the lengths that number of times. Try running it and see.

Comment: Nevermind I misunderstood what the poster wanted.  I see it now.